# Require two identically named classes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, require

In my rails application I connect to another ruby application foo that has a class Database in its folder /classes/database.rb and to another application bar that has another class Databse in its folder /classes/database.rb

In that application I have to put the requires in the application controller. That is done by the following code

```
$: << "C:\foo\
require "plug_in_foo.rb"
```

in the plug_in_foo.rb there are the requires of the foo project, i.e.

```
require "/classes/database.rb"
```

as in the foo project so for the bar project

```
$: << "C:\bar\
require "plug_in_bar.rb"
```

and in the plug_in_bar.rb there are the requires of the bar project, i.e.

```
require "/classes/database.rb"
```

The Database class in the bar project has its own module wrapped around it but when I try to access the class by BaRModule::Datbase.new it is recognized as an unitialized constant so I think that the require does not work.

Can someone help me with this? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require the absolute paths to the different database files.

(You might also check, if you really need to add all this stuff to your load path)

Answer (score -1):

you should include both of your module in your class like `include BaRModule`

Comment: the foo module is not registered as the file name is the same as in the bar project

Comment: register as foo module first and try

Comment: I wrapped the database class of the foo project in a FooModule but also require "/classes/database.rb" does not find the database.rb of the bar project

Comment: your path is wrong. when anything require,just write filename without extention.